# Simple search function in meteor using EasySearch package

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Good Day,

I'm trying to create a simple search function using the easy search package.

In a nutshell I have done the following-

Defined a schema and index on the client as such:

```js
const Patients = new Mongo.Collection('patients');

const PatientsIndex = new EasySearch.Index({
    collection: Patients,
    fields: ['name'],
    engine: new EasySearch.MongoDB()
  });
```

I've entered the following values into the database:

```js
meteor:PRIMARY> db.patients.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57d6a9f71bad26ba07748f9d"), "name" : "Paul" }
```

Created a template helper on the client side:

```js
Template.searchBox.helpers({
  patientsIndex: () => PatientsIndex
});
```

And lastly I've created a template which should output the results:

```html
<template name="searchBox">
    {{> EasySearch.Input index=patientsIndex }}
    <ul>
        {{#EasySearch.Each index=patientsIndex }}
            <li>Name of the patient: {{name}}</li>
        {{/EasySearch.Each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

Now for some reason this just wont work, it renders nothing to the template, I' very new to this and would really appreciate some assistance.

Thanking you.

Answer (score 0):

From your code samples it looks like you're trying to refer to both `Patients` and `PatientsIndex` globally. Assuming you have your `Patients` and `PatientsIndex` declarations in a shared client/server location (like `/lib`), then you should remove the `const` keyword. That will make sure these declarations are available globally, and will allow your Template to use them. Here's a modified version of your code that will work:

**/lib/collection.js**

```
Patients = new Mongo.Collection('patients');

PatientsIndex = new EasySearch.Index({
  collection: Patients,
  fields: ['name'],
  engine: new EasySearch.MongoDB()
});
```

**/client/main.html**

```
<body>
  {{> searchBox}}
</body>

<template name="searchBox">
  {{> EasySearch.Input index=patientsIndex }}
  <ul>
    {{#EasySearch.Each index=patientsIndex }}
      <li>Name of the patient: {{name}}</li>
    {{/EasySearch.Each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

**/client/main.js**

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import './main.html';

Template.searchBox.helpers({
  patientsIndex() {
    return PatientsIndex;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance, I understand now and it makes perfect sense, it's working nicely. As a matter of interest, how can I go about returning the results in a grid?