# Meteor.users collection search with EasySearch

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I’m trying to search `Meteor.users` collection document using EasySearch package but strange not returning any user, I have implemented the search for some other collections & it’s working but not working while implemented in `Meteor.users`, here is my implementation

in the API

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { EasySearch } from 'meteor/easy:search';

export const UsersIndex = new EasySearch.Index({
    collection: Meteor.users,
    fields: ['username', 'createdAt'],
    engine: new EasySearch.MongoDB()
});
```

in the client

```
import { UsersIndex } from './../../api/users';

Tracker.autorun(() => {
    let usersSearch = UsersIndex.search('');
    console.log('Users', usersSearch.fetch());
    console.log('Users Count', usersSearch.count());
});
```

the output is

```
Users []
Users Count 0
```

what is the issue actually?

Thanks

Comment: This question may have already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39451379/simple-search-function-in-meteor-using-easysearch-package

Answer (score 0):

The Meteor `users` collection is special. Basically you can't just search it, for security reasons.

It just can't be treated like normal collections. I suggest creating another table like `members`, or `visitors`, which you will be able to search at will.